# Editing long chapter titles

Tags: chapters

I'm now writing a second chapter in my report document. The title of the second chapter is a little bit long so it's touching the edge of the paper. How can I move part of it to a new line? Here is my code:

```
\documentclass[10pt]{report} 
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage[left=35mm,right=35mm,top=35mm,bottom=35mm]{geometry} 
\titleformat{\section}{\Huge\bfseries}{\thesection}{1em}{}
\titleformat{\chapter}{\huge\bfseries}{\thesection}{1em}{}
\titlespacing*{\section} {0pt}{3.5ex plus 1ex minus .2ex}{8.3ex plus .2ex}
\titlespacing*{\chapter}{0pt}{3.5cm}{2cm}
\linespread{1.8}
\setlength\parindent{0pt}
\begin{document} 
\chapter*{Kapitel 1} 
\section*{Einleitung} 
\subsection*{1.1 Motivation}  
\begin{large}
bla bla bla 
\end{large}  
\chapter*{Kapitel 2} 
\section*{Begriffsdefinitionen und Wissenschaftliche Grundlagen} 
\subsection*{2.1 Nickelbasiswerkstoffe: Historische Entwicklung}  
\begin{large} 
bla bla bla
\end{large}
\end{document}
```

Can you please help?[image: Screenshot of my document]

Comment: `\\ ` should work, you might also want to put a shorter version in a `[...]` argument for the table of contents and the page head.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle thank you David it worked. One more question. Can I also edit for example the spacing or font of the second title without changing anything in the first? I need to reduce the spacing between _Kapitel 2_ and the title of the chapter.

Comment: It's normally considered bad style to change the heading layout for different chapters it's possible of course as you are using `titkesec` you'll need to look at the length parameters that uses and just change them then change them back.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you're taking a wrong approach. You don't need to use `\chapter*{Kapitel 1}` in order to get that header, just use `babel` with the `ngerman` option, which will also give you correct hyphenation. Using `\large` for getting a larger text font is better substituted by passing the `12pt` option to the document class.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{report}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}

\usepackage[a4paper,left=35mm,right=35mm,top=35mm,bottom=35mm]{geometry}

\linespread{1.8}
\setlength\parindent{0pt}

\begin{document}
\chapter{Einleitung}
\section{Motivation}
bla bla bla

\chapter{Begriffsdefinitionen und Wissenschaftliche Grundlagen}
\section{Nickelbasiswerkstoffe: Historische Entwicklung}
bla bla bla
\end{document}
```

[image]

You may want to change the last section title to

```
\section[Nickelbasiswerkstoffe: Historische Entwicklung]
{Nickelbasiswerkstoffe: Historische\\ Entwicklung}
```

to avoid the bad line break. Or use `\titlesec` and specify `\raggedright` for sections, for instance

```
\usepackage{titlesec}
\titleformat{\section}[block]
  {\Large\bfseries}
  {\thesection}
  {1em}
  {\raggedright}
```

[image]

This would free you from the need of specifying twice the title.

Comment: Ok, but if I need to change the font and spacings of the section titles I'll need to use the `titlesec` package, right? Because I want to reduce the spacing above _Einleitung 1_ on the first page for example. I used the command `\titlespacing*{\section} {0pt}{3.5ex plus 1ex minus .2ex}{8.3ex plus .2ex}` but I still don't understand what these numbers are. How can I move the _Einleitung_ one unit upwards?

Comment: @abdu "Einleitung" is the chapter title; you use `\titleformat{\chapter}` command to modify it. With `\titlespacing` you act on the spaces before and after the chapter/section title. The manual of `titletoc` has many examples.

Comment: _Einleitung_ is the section. The chapter in my case is _Kapitel 1_ =)

Comment: @abdu I don't think so. Why should it be? With `\chapter{Einleitung}` the words "Kapitel 1" are automatically added.